# iOS 13 Siri Shortcuts Deep Linking

Tags: swift, ios12, ios13

I read somewhere that Siri Shortcuts will change in IOS 13.
Does anyone know if they made changes in Swift with Siri Shortcuts Deep Links?
Now in ios 12 i made a function:

```
func run(shortcutName: String) {
        let url = URL(string: shortcutName)!
        UIApplication.shared.open(url,
                                  options: [:],
                                  completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

And to use this i simply call `run(shortcutName: shortcutNameString)`

Does anyone know if this code will work and run a shortcut on IOS 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! Use this URL scheme: `shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=SHORTCUT%20NAME%20HERE`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the time i installed ios 13 and saw that it’s working but forgot to remove my question here:D

Comment: Why removing a question? It's good to have that as a reference for everyone.